# How to head a CSV file using SheetJS keeping all values as strings

Tags: typescript, csv, sheetjs

I need to implement a CSV parser. I choose SheetJS to do it.

But when I parse a file to json, SheetJS converts iso date strings to a javascript Date and/or decimal numbers and also converts digits strings to numbers. For example, the value 045 will be converted to 45.

I whould like to know how to parse a csv without type inference.